# C# index not in context

Tags: c#

I am can't figure out how to put the index [i] in the context when I try to write in to the listbox1. The code I got so far is:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        StreamWriter Info = File.AppendText("Contacts.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++);
            Info.WriteLine(listBox1.Items[i]);
        Info.Close();
    }
```

I am trying to make a Windows Form application that accepts names and email addresses and places them in a list box. Can anyone help me out on what I am missing here?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make a list of email contacts

Comment: You said you are adding items in listbox, but in code you are doing opposite i.e. writing listbox items to a file ?

Comment: If you show you sample output, that will probably help us to get what you want to do

Comment: the output in the list box would look something like this:   
           
Tom Spickler     
TSpic@gmail.com
Jessica Murray
Jmurray@yahoo.com

Answer (score 10):

The semicolon in this line `for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++);` may cause an error. Delete it and then try again.

Comment: oh yeah the one at the end, well spotted

Comment: because of this, that would not be going into the loop

Comment: That worked removing that semicolon now once the button is pressed it does not display in the listbox, how come?

Comment: @user2514327 what doesn't display in the `listbox`? while asking something, ask in detail. Don't be precise

Comment: You already got an answer on that question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265143/c-sharp-index-not-in-context/17265196?noredirect=1#comment25026083_17265143) You are doing it in a wrong direction. With your code, you are writing content from listbox to a file.

Comment: Can I also suggest following the StyleCop suggestion of using {} for all loops including one-liners; Microsoft added this as an internal review found it to be a common source of bugs similar to yours

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to do. I am providing you the possible solutions here as i understood your problem.

1. If you need to write a file with `listbox1` contents, same code with correction by Misa Lazovic:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {            
       StreamWriter Info = File.AppendText("Contacts.txt");

       for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
           Info.WriteLine(listBox1.Items[i]);
       Info.Close();
   }
   ```
2. If you need to read the contents from file and place them to your `listbox1`:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {            
       foreach (string s in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Contacts.txt"))
               listBox1.Items.Add(s);
   }
   ```